# RecyclerView setOnLongClickListener kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

First of all :
I would like to pass data from my RecyclerAdapter to my Fragment, so it's in that way that I implemented this adapter below :

```
class RecyclerItemCart(private val cart: MutableList<Post>, val context: Context, val listener: (Post) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerItemCart.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClickListener(post: Post)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(cart[position], listener)
        holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener {
            true }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cart.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder (val mView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView) {
        fun bind(mItem: Post, listener: (Post) -> Unit) = with(itemView)
        {
            val title: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.title)
            val authorName: TextView = mView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.owner)
            val priceIT: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.priceIncT)
            val priceExcT: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.priceExcT)
            val pic: ImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.pic)
            title.text = mItem.title
            authorName.text = mItem.authorName
            priceIT.text = mItem.priceIT
            priceExcT.text = mItem.priceExcT
            //        Glide.with(context).load(mItem.url).into(pic)
            setOnLongClickListener { listener(mItem)
                true }
        }
    }
}
```

then I set the onLongClickListener in my fragment (version 1) :

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_fragment, container, false)
        activity = getActivity() as MainActivity
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recylerItemCart)

        totalAmountView = v.findViewById(R.id.total_amount)
        activity.toolbarTitle.text = resources.getString(R.string.cart)
        RequestGetCart.MakeRequestTask(this, activity).execute(activity.user.token)
        v.findViewById<Button>(R.id.checkout).setOnClickListener(this)
        recyclerView.setOnLongClickListener {
            recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerItemCart(cart.elements, activity){
                RequestRemoveItemCart.MakeRequestTask(this, activity).execute(activity.user.token, it.id, "1")
            }
           AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle("REMOVE ITEM")
                .setMessage(context!!.resources.getString(R.string.removeItemCart))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerItemCart(cart.elements, activity){
                        RequestRemoveItemCart.MakeRequestTask(this, activity).execute(activity.user.token, it.id, "1")
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show()
            true}
        return v
    }
```

but when I try to longClick, nothing happens. It never enters in the listener.

So I tried to modify a bit as :

```
recyclerView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
            true
             }) {
            recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerItemCart(cart.elements, activity){
                RequestRemoveItemCart.MakeRequestTask(this, activity).execute(activity.user.token, it.id, "1")
            }
           AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle("REMOVE ITEM")
                .setMessage(context!!.resources.getString(R.string.removeItemCart))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerItemCart(cart.elements, activity){
                        RequestRemoveItemCart.MakeRequestTask(this, activity).execute(activity.user.token, it.id, "1")
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show()
            true}
```

But I have an error when I use

```
recyclerView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
            true
             })
```

it's saying I don't pass good arguments, but I pass the View.onLongClickListener as asked.
If you have any idea about this setOnLongClickListener or another way to handle a longClick and pass data from Recycler to a fragment.
Only one condition : I want to do stuff in my fragment not in my recycler.

So for example I can catch onLongClick from Adapter and call a callback to go back to fragment but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you want to listen to long clicks on every `itemView` or on whole `recyclerView`?

Comment: @underoid on every itemView. For example when I long click on item 1 I want to show title of item 1 (from fragment as I said before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adapter code is ok except redundant `OnItemClickListener`. Since you pass the listener in adapter constructor, your callback method will be lambda where you initialize the adapter.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    ...
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recylerItemCart)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerItemCart(cart.elements, activity) {
        //this is the lambda (listener) that you pass to the adapter,
        // and this will be called when long click occurs on itemView as it has already set in ViewHolder
    }
    ...
    return v
}
```

Comment: I also deleted le setOnLongClickListener in the onBindViewHolder in the adapter and it's working as you said when I pass the lambda ! Thanks you !